# Отредактировать кнопки в приложении

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```py
from tkinter import *  

a = 0
def clicked():
    global a
    a += 1  
    
b = 0
def clicked1():
    global b
    b += 1
    
c = 0
def clicked2():
    global c
    c = a*b

    lbl.configure(text=f"Сила : {a}")  
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)
    
    lbl1.configure(text=f"Маст : {b}") 
    lbl1.grid(column=0, row=2) 
  
    lbl2.configure(text=f"kombo : {c}")  
    lbl2.grid(column=0, row=3)
  
window = Tk()  

lbl = Label(window, text=f"Сила : ")  
lbl.grid(column=0, row=1)

lbl1 = Label(window, text=f"Маст : ") 
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=2) 


lbl2 = Label(window, text=f"komb : ") 
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=3) 

btn = Button(window, text="+", command=clicked)  
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)  

btn1 = Button(window, text="+", command=clicked1)  
btn1.grid(column=1, row=2)  


btn2 = Button(window, text="kombo", command=clicked2)  
btn2.grid(column=1, row=3)  

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых отформатируйте вопрос. Во-вторых объясните толком что вы хотите отредактировать и что у вас не получается. А то мы при всем желании не сможем вам помочь(

Comment: В общем у меня есть 3 кнопки когда нажимаю на первую или вторую кнопку текст возле кнопки не обновляется, но если нажать на кнопку 3 то всё обновится.Нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любую кнопку даные обновлялись

Comment: Что написано в функциях, то они и делают. Если вы хотите, чтоб они делали что-то другое - поменяйте код в них.